# Array and function c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I built a program that accepts two input from the user, using a array inside a loop, it is passed to a function inside a class which will display the two number.

The problem is when the user is inputting a number and it is 1. The program continuously asks the user to input a number, and when 2 is entered the program ask another number and end, but for example you entered 2 and 3. . . it will then output 2 and 4 (so 3 + 1 ) and always the last number is plus one. Here is the code:

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "newclass.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int array_variable_main[2];
    for(int counter = 1; counter <= 2; counter=counter+1)
    {
        cout << "Enter a Number: " << endl;
        cin >> array_variable_main[counter];
    }
    newclass sum_object;
    sum_object.loop_function(array_variable_main, 2);
    return 0;
}
```

newclass.cpp:

```
#include "newclass.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
newclass::newclass()
{
}
void newclass::loop_function(int array_variable[], int arraysize)
{
    cout << "The numbers that are stored in the array are: " << endl;
    for(int counter = 1; counter <= arraysize; counter = counter+1)
    {
        cout << array_variable[counter] << endl;
    }
}
```

newclass.h:

```
#ifndef NEWCLASS_H
#define NEWCLASS_H
class newclass
{
public:
    newclass();
    void loop_function(int array_variable[], int arraysize);
};
#endif // NEWCLASS_H
```

Comment: Array indices start from 0

Comment: @chris sir i already tried doing this and it did not solve the problem, any other suggestion sir? thanks.

Comment: That's the only definitively wrong thing I see.

Answer (score 2):

You have to remember that array indices go from zero to size-1. So for your array it's zero and one. Anything beyond that leads to undefined behavior. Undefined behavior can't easily be predicted, so the result of your program could be anything.

Comment: Sir I already tried declaring my counter to 0 but it did not solve the problem any other suggestion sir? thanks.

Comment: @user3086565 Did you ALSO remember to change the comparision part of the `for` header from `counter <=` to `counter <`, and in *both* places you made the error?

Comment: Sir I just want to verify if i got it right. . . so basically if I want to use an array with a storage of 3, then i must use a loop that has a counter starting in zero and a condition that is counter < 3. . . and then if i use a array[4] then the loop (counter=0; counter<4; ++counter). thanks sir XD.

Answer (score 2):

In C and C++ array index normally starts at 0 so this

```
int array_variable_main[2];
for(int counter = 1; counter <= 2; counter=counter+1)
{
  cout << "Enter a Number: " << endl;
  cin >> array_variable_main[counter];
}
```

will access outside the array

do instead

```
int array_variable_main[2];
for(int counter = 0; counter < 2; ++counter)
{
  cout << "Enter a Number: " << endl;
  cin >> array_variable_main[counter];
}
```

Comment: sir i already tried this one, it did not solve the problem sir, any other suggestion? thank.

Comment: Sir im sorry, the code that you gave me works! thank you very much XD until next time.